# Atomikos / Spring - Global Transaction over two DBs

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, transactions, jta

I am using Spring and trying to setup a global transaction spanning over two MS SQL Server DBs. The app is running inside Tomcat 6.

I have these definitions:

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
....
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory1"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
....
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager1"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory1"/>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
....
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory2"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
....
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager2"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory2"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then also, each DAO is linked either to `sessionFactory1` or to `sessionFactory2`.

```
<bean name="stateHibernateDao" class="com.project.dao.StateHibernateDao">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1"/>
</bean>
```

Also, I recently added these two.

```
<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close"> 
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp"> 
   <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" /> 
</bean>
```

I am trying to programmatically manage the global transaction
(this is some old legacy code and I don't want to change it too
much so I prefer keeping this managed programmatically).

So now I have this `UserTransaction ut` (injected from Spring), so I call `ut.begin()`, do some DB/DAO operations to the two DBs through the DAOs, then I call `ut.commit()`.

The thing is that even before the `ut.commit()` call, I can see the data is already committed to the DBs?!

1. I don't think Atomikos is aware of my two DBs, their data sources, session factories, etc. I don't think it starts any transactions on them. Looks like they are not enlisted at all in the global transaction.
2. To me it seems that each DB/DAO operation goes to the SQL Server on its own, so SQL Server creates an implicit transaction for just that DAO/DB operation, applies the operation and commits the implicit the transaction.

But 1) and 2) are just guesses of mine.

My questions:

1. Do I need to start the two DB transactions myself (but OK, this is what I am currently doing and I am trying to get rid of; that's why I am trying to use Atomikos to start with)?
2. How I can configure all this correctly so that when I call `ut.begin()` it begins a global transaction to the two DBs and when I call `ut.commit()` it commits it?
3. I haven't played with JTA recently so seems to me I am missing something quite basic here. What is it?

### Edit 1

```
<bean id="globalTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionSynchronization" value="2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Yuor configuration is lacking XA datasources, and you don't have a JtaTransactionManager to manage your transactions you still have the HibernateTransactionManager. Next to that you seem to have missed the proper hibernate setup for JTA. I suggest a read of th Atomikos documentation for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your note. Can you point me to something more specific especially about the XA Datasources? I had the JtaTransactionManager in at some point. I will try it again. The two HibernateTransactionManagers are defined but not used currently. Do I need to call begin and commit on the JtaTransactionManager or on the Atomikos impl TM?

Comment: JTA will only work with datasources that support it, currently you only have non xa datasources. And as mentioned you don't seem to have configured hibernate correctly for JTA with Atomikos either. If I recall correctly atomikos has xa wrappers for datasources.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks again. Even by using JtaTransactionManager it does not work (I mean I see the same behavior). I call getUserTransaction on that manager, then I call begin/commit/rollback on the UserTransaction. Still no luck. I read that even non-XA datasources can participate in a global transaction but seems the setup is more complex than that or I am still missing something basic here. See "Edit 1".

Comment: You can have a single non xa resource participating in a global transaction not multiple. As mentioned if you don't setup things correctly (datasources, hibernate) it isn't going to work. You cannot just slap a `UserTransactionManager` etc. in there and expect it to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum But even on the 1st datasource, I don't get why it's committing all the data before I call the ut.commit. Seems this UserTransactionManager is currently totally disconnected from my two non XA datasources. They are both not under its control, that's what it seems to me.

Comment: It commits because there is no transaction, at least hibernate thinks so. As mentioned it isn't only the datasources you also need to configure hibernate correctly.